# How to format a date in a javascript?possible

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, datetime, date, formatting

How can I format a date object to print as today instead of showing a numeric date in a javascript?

I'd like to display it like this: **today **At 5:00 PM****.

- js

  ```
   var today = new Date();
  var date = new Date(today)
  date.setDate(date.getDate()-1)
  today.toDateString()
  date.toDateString()
   var time = today.toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'});
  var dateTime = date+' '+time;
  this.dateTimeValue=dateTime;
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to take a look at the [**lightning-formatted-date-time** component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-date-time/example) to achieve this.

With this component one can format the date in many ways using the component's API:

```html
<p>
  <lightning-formatted-date-time
    value="1547250828000"
    year="2-digit"
    month="short"
    day="2-digit"
    weekday="narrow"
  ></lightning-formatted-date-time>

  <!-- this outputs "Jan 11, 2019" -->
</p>
```

---

If you are looking for a pure JavaScript approach, without using Salesforce things, this is not the appropriate community to ask for help. But since we are here, take a look at the [Internationalization API for DateTimeFormat in Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat).

Comment: need with string today instead of showing the date in numeric value. i need to show to today At 5:00pm

Comment: Then just check if the date equals to today's date and append the "Today at" string before displaying the time.

Comment: This is my code i used `var today = new Date();
        var date = new Date(today)
        date.setDate(date.getDate()-1)
        today.toDateString()
        date.toDateString()
        var time = today.toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'});
        var dateTime = date+' '+time;
        this.dateTimeValue=dateTime;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lightning-relative-date-time](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-relative-date-time/example), although that won't say "today at 5PM", but it'd say something like "in about 5 hours" (assuming it was noon of the same day). Otherwise, you'd have to use something like MomentJS to get fancier, or write your own custom logic.

Comment: we add if condition to display today date with time